# How to write a function to create and return a random engine in c++

Tags: c++, random

I have been struggling with C++ pseudo-random-number generation. I would like to write a method `createRandEngine` to render a random engine. Then some other method (per say `gaussian`) uses this engine to generate random numbers. I've tried the following code, but I got two compile-time errors from the line **.

```
#include <random>

typedef std::default_random_engine rand_engine;
rand_engine createRandEngine(const int &seed)
{
    std::seed_seq _s (unsigned(seed));
    rand_engine _eng(_s);  //**

    return _eng;    // Check if we can find alternative ways to render _eng
}


double gaussian(rand_engine &eng, const double &u, const double &std_dev)
{
    std::normal_distribution<double> _g(u, std_dev);
    double _val = _g(eng);
    return _val;
}


int main ()
{
    rand_engine eng = createRandEngine(20190117);
    double norm     = gaussian(eng, 0., 1.);

    std::cout << std::to_string(norm);
}
```

The two errors state:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul>::seed(std::seed_seq (&)(unsigned int))’


error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’ linear_congruential_engine<_UIntType, __a, __c, __m>::
```

I am relatively new to C++. Any help with my code or showing your ways to do it will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::seed_seq` is something from C++11, so I believe you can use the brace syntax at declaring variables:

```
typedef std::default_random_engine rand_engine;
rand_engine createRandEngine(const int &seed)
{
    std::seed_seq _s {unsigned(seed)};
    rand_engine _eng {_s};

    return _eng;    // Check if we can find alternative ways to render _eng
}
```

This, as I tested, will generate no warning or error (and make your intention to pass parameter to constructors more explicit).

Now, let's see why you failed. You try to initialize `_s` as `std::__1::seed_seq(unsigned int)` type (according to my clang compiler) but what you intended to do is to pass on a one-element list to the `std::seed_seq`. So the brace expression make you more explicit that you want that as a list, although there is only one element. A pair of parentheses, however, make the notation a bit ambiguous and my clang mistaken you intention.

See the examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq/seed_seq, using braces to initialize is recommended.